# Does any one know how to find following string using regular expression of visual studio?

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2005

Does any one know how to find following string using regular expression of visual studio?

```
  <fo:block>

  </fo:block>
```

I have tried with following but it didn't work

```
\<fo\:block\>*$\n*\</fo\:block\>$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me but it's not pretty...

```
\<fo\:block\>.*\x0d\x0a.*\x0d\x0a.*\<\/fo\:block\>
```

I thought I tried this:

```
\<fo\:block\>.*\n.*\n.*\<\/fo\:block\>
```

yesterday but apparently I didn't because it works.

Comment: could you explain a about \x0d\x0a.*\x0d\x0a

Comment: x0d = CR (Carriage Return) and x0a = LF (Linefeed) but now it seems \n works just as fine.